# Why does my service account not give remote access to Google Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I followed the instructions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart
to get my Node app working with Firestore (under **Initialize on your own server**). I created a service account like they say, giving it the the "Cloud Firestore Editor" privilege and downloaded the `.json` key file. When I run the example code like so though:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./gcloud-service-account.json')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

var db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })

var docRef = db.collection('users').doc('alovelace');

var setAda = docRef.set({
  first: 'Ada',
  last: 'Lovelace',
  born: 1815
});
```

I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

What am I doing wrong, or what steps could I take to debug this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Never mind.... It was the last step of service account creation I was missing - you have to grant user access to itself for some reason, so put the newly created account name in the "grant users" box. Hope that helps someone.